# Easy way of getting unique id

Tags: php, mysql

When i insert into table, how can i get the unique id of that table row without doing another query by selecting last inserted element.

lets say i do something like this:

```
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `user_table` SET user_email='efwwe', user_pw='fwefwef'; ");
```

now i want to get the user_id from that last insertion. Is it possible to get this from the php $query variable? Or do i really need to do another query where i select the last row from user_table? user_id would be the unique id that is incremented automaticly in this case

regards,
alexander

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you're looking for the [`mysql_insert_id()`](http://php.net/mysql_insert_id) function.

ex:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO mytable (product) values ('kossu')");
printf("Last inserted record has id %d\n", mysql_insert_id());
```

Comment: or, more roundabout-ish, `SELECT last_insert_id()` using the same database handle as the original query. But the direct function call is definitely more efficient/faster.

Answer (score 1):

I think this can be easily done by [mysql_insert_id()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php);

Answer (score 1):

[mysql_insert_id](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php) should give you what you want, assuming the identity columns of your tables are set up as AUTO_INCREMENT